# What am i doing wrong? create xml using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am following this tutorial step by step http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html . Actually I copy pasted the code and created the database, added the data to the table, downloaded the provided php and html files but when i actually try to run the page that will create the xml file i get this error. Can anyone guess what is wrong? I am using  XAMPP
1.7.4 
[PHP: 5.3.5]

(The google tutorial suggests 3 ways to generate the xml file. I tried all 3 of them and the same error appears on the first 2 and an "error on line 10" (which is the line that php script begins) appears when i try the 3rd suggested way. I am thinking if this wont work to use mysqldump command in order to export the xml file i need.)
[image] [image]

Comment: I don't know much about this, but could the fact that you have declared the content type to be `text/html` be the problem?

Comment: You clearly *didn't* follow the tutorial correctly, otherwise you'd have only `<markers>...</markers>` as your output.

Comment: Well i just copy pasted the provided code. I dont know why there is an html part above <markers>

Comment: gonna try it and see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-EDIT-**
Problem was in the connection to the database, value for $host and/or $user and/or $pass was incorrect or not provided.

---

If you use version 2 (**phpsqlajax_genxml2**), edit the file at `line 15` replacing `localhost` with `'localhost'`.

If you use version 3 (**phpsqlajax_genxml3**), edit the file at `line 13`replacing `localhost` with `'localhost'`.

Then try again.

Comment: weird I was getting the same error but that fixed it for me, gonna try find something else.

Comment: Nothing changed... I cant explain how html is created out of nothing.

Comment: You know, on your screenshot it says undefined localhost bla bla.., could you post a screenshot of what it says after you replace `localhost` for `'localhost`'.

Comment: I edited the screenshot. Is there a chance that it is apache's fault?

Comment: You know, I have no idea, I reduced the script to try and find the culprit but it still seems like it's the connection line to me, could you try the following: https://gist.github.com/1236521 and tell me if you can get an xml without un-commenting anything? if not I give up :S

Comment: Well at first it works. xml is created. but when i uncomment and put my password i get again the error "extra content at the end of ..."

Comment: That's why I believe there is the error since by uncommenting we're simply creating the connection not echoing anything so it shouldn't affect the result.

Comment: Told you it was the connection LOL Still remember to put the username and password in a separated file and call it as variables, I just put everything in a single file to simplify the code and pin-point the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have two root elements in your XHTML: `html` and `markers`. This is why your browser *correctly* considers it to be invalid.

The problem with blindly copying/pasting code is that when you come across a problem it's very difficult to solve, because you don't understand what the code is doing. I suggest you read through the code closely. When you understand it, you'll be able to fix it.

Essentially you'll want to remove all of the output up until the `<markers>` tag. Perhaps the HTML file you're using is incorrect.

Comment: there is no obvious problem. It is copy paste from google tutorial.

Comment: Include the page source in your question.

Comment: i posted a print screen of the source